# С++. Дважды прочитать файл. Библиотека fstream

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

Доброго времени суток.

Возник такой вопрос. Как в библиотеке `fstream` дважды прочитать файл без его закрытия?

Нашел функции `rewind()` и `fseek(file,0L,SEEK_SET)`, но они отказываются работать, если открывать файл не функцией `fopen` из библиотеки `stdio.h`

Есть ли альтернатива для библиотеки `fstream`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите на [`seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). И, если нарвались на конец файла или иные неприятности - не забывайте сбросить состояние ошибки с помощью [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).